# Is it true that $\bigcap_{k\geq0} C^{k, \alpha}(\Omega)=C^\infty(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I've been reading about regularity theorems. It is a well known fact that for $p>1$, one has that
$$\bigcap_{k\geq0} W^{k, p}(\Omega)=C^\infty(\Omega)$$
This is often stated in analysis and PDE books.
Now, I'm wondering whether the same result holds for Holder spaces, namely :
$$\bigcap_{k\geq0} C^{k, \alpha}(\Omega)=C^\infty(\Omega)$$
Here, I'm assuming that $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is open. Perhaps we need $\Omega$ to be bounded or some boundary condition for equality to hold?
I'll be glad if you can point me a precise reference regarding this, or an actual reason for this to hold "trivially" (I've encountered this implicitily in some papers but they never bother to explain or point out a reference)

Comment: There are simple counterexamples for $n = 1$, like $x^\beta$ on $(0, 1)$ with $0 < \beta < \alpha$, which is smooth but not $\alpha$-Hölder and this can probably be extended easily to arbitrary $n$, so you will need more restrictions.

Comment: Every $C^{k,\alpha}$ function is $C^k$. Hence every function in the intersection is $C^\infty$. The only problem is the converse inclusion.